# How to delete the last letter in the word if it is 'a' or 'o'?

Tags: python

I've got txt file with list of words, something like this:

```
adsorbowanie
adsorpcje
adular
adwena
adwent
adwentnio
adwentysta
adwentystka
adwersarz
adwokacjo
```

And I want to delete the last letter in every word, if that letter is "a" or "o".

I'm very new to this, so please explain this simply.

Comment: There is an endswith() method

Answer (score 1):

```
re.sub(r"[ao]$","",word)
```

This should do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
import os

# Read the file, split the contents into a list of lines, 
# removing line separators
with open('input.txt') as infile:
    lines = infile.read().splitlines()

# Remove any whitespace around the word.
# If you are certain the list doesn't contain whitespace
# around the word, you can leave this out...
# (this is called a "list comprehansion", by the way)
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]

# Remove letters if necessary, using regular expressions.
outlines = [re.sub('[ao]$', '', line) for line in lines]

# Join the output with appropriate line separators
outdata = os.linesep.join(outlines)

# Write the output to a file
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(outdata)
```

Comment: That was very helpful! Thanks :D

Comment: When you strip the text, the expression should be `line.strip()` instead of `lines.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

First read the file and split the lines. After that cut off the last char if your condition is fulfilled and append the new string to a list containing the analysed and modified strings/lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

# open file, read lines and store them in a list
with open('words.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

# analyse lines read from file
new_lines = []
for s in lines:
    # analyse last char of string,
    # get rid of it if condition is fulfilled and append string to new list
    s = s[:-1] if s[-1] in ['a', 'o'] else s
    new_lines.append(s)

print(new_lines)
```